# Is there a Ruby SASL client gem?

Tags: ruby, sasl

I'd like to authenticate users of a little web service against an existing Dovecot SASL service. Any gem that can do that?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you need:

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pyu-ruby-sasl/0.0.3.3

Or this:

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/gsasl/1.0.0

Both seem to not be native ruby though, and depend on stuff being already installed in your system beforehand. If you were looking for something like that, there doesn't seem to be anything released by the open source community just yet.

Comment: I ended up writing my own tiny SASL client. It took all of 7 lines of Ruby. I could not figure out how to use either of the two you linked.

Comment: Now it's time for you to set the example to the rest of the ruby community by opensourcing your client ;)

Comment: I would, if it wasn't a very hacky auth-only client. I have no current plans of supporting all of SASL, which is quite a lot. The `gsasl` gem probably does that, but could do with some love and documentation.